# « ... has aerosolized » : « aérosoliser » est-il rare et que dit-on plus couramment ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, lexique, santé-et-médecine

Dans un film<sup>1</sup> (*Outbreak*, 1995, W. Petersen) j'entends :

> We're in deep shit, Billy. The virus has [**aerosolized**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aerosolise#English).

On parle de « pulvériser en état d’aérosol ; disperser dans l’air sous forme d’aérosol, en parlant d’un liquide ou d’un solide micronisé » (Wiktionnaire). Wiktionnaire dit que l'emploi du verbe [*aérosoliser*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%C3%A9rosoliser) (et de l'[adjectif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%C3%A9rosolis%C3%A9)) est rare *en français* et plusieurs exemples réfèrent à un traitement, plutôt qu'à ce qui fait qu'un traitement soit requis.

L'emploi est-il vraiment rare ? Que dit-on plus couramment ? Est-ce « se disperse dans l'air » ou « (est) sous forme d'[aérosol](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%C3%A9rosol) » ou les deux et pourquoi dans ce dernier cas y aurait-il redondance ou non ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Malheureusement aussi dans l'[actualité](https://www.cnn.com/2020/04/02/health/aerosol-coronavirus-spread-white-house-letter/index.html), quoique différemment et l'analyse de ce genre de propos ne relève pas de l'objet du site.</sub>

Comment: Le virus *[s’]est dispersé dans l’atmosphère/l’air* — sans le *[s’]* c’est le vent qui l’a mis ainsi, avec le *[s’]* il s’est propagé on ne sait pas comment, mais il est dans l’air que l’on respire — ***aérosoliser*** n’est pas reconnu par l’Académie française, c’est un anglicisme à éviter qui fait partie des jargons techniques (peut-être dû aux traducteurs automates), à ne pas utiliser.

Comment: @Personne Je t'invite à produire une réponse stp. Il y a par ailleurs le [substantif](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=AEROSOLISATION&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs). Comme tu sais, bien des choses ne sont pas reconnues par l'Ac. mais je préfère quand l'Ac. prend position contre et motive. C'est possible que ce soit des traductions automatiques ou participatives anglicisantes. Je ne sais pas.

Comment: @Personne Oui, je comprends, je sais qui tu es, mais remarque Gilles continue de rédiger des réponses sur U&L et même ici il a rédigé une réponse dernièrement. Il ne s'agit pas des points, simplement qu'en réponse on peut développer davantage etc. C'est plus intéressant. Et notre échange finit par court-circuiter la réponse qui se trouve plus bas. Évidemment, tu es libre. Salutations !

Comment: Même si *aérosoliser* était agréé par l’intégration des évolutions pérennes dans les dictionnaires, le commun des mortels laisse les mots de six syllabes aux spécialistes.

Comment: Notre jargon de base : des néologismes tirés du grec et du latin, des échanges des deux côtés de la Manche et "La Belle Province" comme conservatoire. Si *aéroliser* descend de son piédestal technico-scientifique propulsé par un savant sachant et renommé sur les media de communications au cours d’une épidémie, après une période purgative il commencera par entrer aux Larousse, même si le Québec lui trouve une translittération sympathique :-) — Pour ma part, je laisse à César ce qui est à César et aux Anglais ce qui vient de leur île isolée de l’Europe, même si Académie.fr  manque de femmes.

Answer (score 1):

Je n'ai jamais entendu « aérosoliser », ça doit être employé uniquement dans des contextes techniques précis. « Se disperser dans l'air » est ce qui me semble la tournure la plus compréhensible, le terme d'« aérosol » étant peu souvent utilisé.

« Se disperser dans l'air sous forme d'aérosol » est redondant, puisque pour se disperser dans l'air il faut forcément être sous forme de particules fines, donc un aérosol.

Comment: De la cendre peut-elle se disperser dans l'air ? La cendre n'est pas particulièrement particulaire.